# How can I post a question with a long error message in it?

Tags: support, code-formatting

There are other questions that ask this but none of their answers have worked for me. I have a very long error message (well not so very long, 354 chars) and I'm trying to show it in a question I am trying to post. But no matter what I do I get the message telling me it is code and I ought to indent it by 4 chars or use ctrl/k.

Here is what I've tried:

- surrounding it with <code> tags, including the comment tag above like this: <!-- language: lang-none -->
- using <pre><code> instead
- using just <pre>
- using back ticks (ctrl/k does the same thing, so does {})

Other people seem to be doing this okay. What am I missing?

Comment: The 'duplicate' answers are all things I already tried, hence the new question.

Answer (score 0):

One way that works well for me is to:

- Paste your code/error message in to the message dialog box
- Highlight the code/error message
- Then press CTRL K

Alternatively, type the following:

```
<pre><code> Your code </code>
```

Make sure that it is on topic where you are intending to include your code/error message.

Using the error message in your comment:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.jboss.dashboard-builder:dashboard-builder-bom:pom:6.2.0.Beta3 from localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of guvnor-m2-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.dashboard-builder:dashboard-builder-bom:pom:6.2.0.Beta3 from/to guvnor-m2-repo (localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb/maven2): Unauthorized (401)
```

Comment: Yes, sounds good, but what do you mean by 'message dialog box'? If you mean edit box where I enter the message then I already tried this. If you mean something else I'm hopeful this is the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the message dialog box is where you type your question or answer - do you have a link to the question?

Comment: I can't enter the question because of this problem, so there is no link. But this is the error message I'm trying to add to my question: ...too long by 86 characters... I'll try to get it into the next comment.

Comment: Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.jboss.dashboard-builder:dashboard-builder-bom:pom:6.2.0.Beta3 from http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of guvnor-m2-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.dashboard-builder:dashboard-builder-bom:pom:6.2.0.Beta3 from/to guvnor-m2-repo (http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb/maven2/): Unauthorized (401)

Comment: And I did already try <pre><code> as I said in the original question.

Comment: When I tried putting your error message in between those tags and in the way I mentioned above, it seemed to work, except that it was one big line

Comment: Well, I do appreciate your trying it out. It does show as one long line in my preview, but the error box comes up alongside it in the entry box and it won't let me submit it. If no one else can replicate that then it is just one of life's mysteries, as is the original question, of course.